# How to get whether jquery response is a file or not?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        alert(request.responseText);
});
```

Here in this code, it is alerting both js,css file and the plain response. Is there anyway to get only the plain responses.

Comment: Can you provide running code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Can't you add another parameter to return to the request that has a `IsFile = true/false` ? Have the server set the flag based on what it is returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems you are loading via ajax several resources, so you could get the `content-type` response header inside the callback and, if it's `text/html`, you alert the `responseText`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
     var ct = request.getResponseHeader('content-type');
     if (ct === "text/html") {
         alert(request.responseText);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're getting the entire contents of an HTML page (if you are not, then this answer doesn't make sense).

The response is a text blob. You need to handle it as such. You can insert it a DOM, either in the page or in a variable, and parse it from there to extract the parts you want.

You are only receiving ONE file in the request, not separate CSS/JS/HTML.